# Processing Map with in Map values

Tags: java, json

For the below JSON

```
{
    "employee": {
        "insurances": {
            "insurance1": "45.1",
            "insurance2": "505.5"
        }
    },
    "id":61
}
```

Im using below code snippet to retrieve values from each field

```
Map<String, Object> insuranceDetails = (Map) ((Map) sourceAsMap.get("employee"))
    .get("insurances");

insuranceDetails.get("insurance1");
insuranceDetails.get("insurance2");
```

Would like to know is there any better/efficient way to achieve this? It has to run inside the loop so Im worrying about the performance. "insurance1" and "insurance2" are fixed fields.

Comment: Maybe try to parse it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Is it valid JSON?

Comment: Are you using any library for parsing JSON? What type is `sourceAsMap`? How is it build? Why should there be a *more efficient* way to do this using that library? It already looks straight and compact.

Answer (score 3):

It's a better solution to create a entity class which it's properties are according to you json format.

```
class Json {
    long id;
    Map<String, Map<String, Float>> employee;
}
```

or even:

```
class Json {
    long id;
    Map<String, Insurrences> employee;
}

class Insurrences {
    Map<String, Float> insurrences;
}

class Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          String json = "{"employee":{"insurances”:{“insurance1”:”45.1","insurance2”:”505.5”}}, “id":61}";
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          Json jsonObj = gson.fromJson(json, Json.class);
          System.out.println(jsonObj.id);
    }
}
```

output would be: 61

gson librar: https://github.com/google/gson